# What is the expected providerData when using email password authentication?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using GoogleProvider as well as an email password for authentication and I have chosen to store providerData from the userAuth object in my Firestore database. I have a few reasons for wanting to store this data with the user data, one being it aids in helping my app identify the different authProviders my users are using and adjusts the layout accordingly. My issue is I have noticed the providerData is a little strange when using email/password and has things like the **email** as the **phone number** value, it has **null** as the **email** value, it has **email** as the **displayName** value, and it has **password** (*the word password, not the actual password used by the user*) as the **UID** value.

Comment: I also noticed a similarly strange output. For me, the `providerId` for email+password (using the Firebase Auth for Flutter) was the literal string "password" instead of being null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the expected providerData when using email password authentication?

Only the UID and the email address. All the other fields that exist in the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object will be null. If for example, you want to integrate Firebase sign-in with Google, then the `displayName` and `photoUrl` will hold a value too.

Comment: Hey Miguel. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: What about the `providerId` field then? I also got the literal string 'password' for that, neither null nor an empty string.

Comment: @TristanBennett The [getProviderId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getProviderId()) will always returns `FirebaseAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID`.